# How to add variable values after loading rendered and saved Stimulsoft report?

Tags: wpf, render, report

I'm using Stimulsoft Reporting for WPF. I have saved a rendered report (in the database in binary format). When I'm loading the report I can view it in Stimulsoft Report Viewer.

I would like to register a new value for a variable (which was already rendered). Is this posible?

If I'm trying with report["variableName"]="xxxxx" it doesn't do anything.
If I (re)render the report it becomes blank.

Ideeas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for access to variable.

If report compiled:

```
report["variableName"]="xxxxx";
```

If report not compiled:

```
report.Dictionary.Variables["variableName"].Value="xxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

when report is compiled you can access variables via report.CompiledReport.Variables["variableName"]="xxxxx";